# Elvis operator when creating strings

Tags: groovy, operators

I'm starting learning Groovy and I came to this example:

```
message = 'Hello' + userService.getLoggedInUser()?.firstName ?: 'Anonymous'
message += '!'
```

We want that message have the value `Hello Anonymous` when `getLoggedInUser` method return `null`. But with the example above the value of `message` is `Hello null` when the method return a null value.

This example works:

```
message = 'Hello'
message += userService.getLoggedInUser()?.firstName ?: 'Anonymous'
message += '!
```

Why the first example didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because of [operator precedence](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_operator_precedence) (first dots, then `+`, then `?:`)

This will work:

```
message = 'Hello' + (userService.getLoggedInUser()?.firstName ?: 'Anonymous')
message += '!'
```

Or better use GString:s instead of concating:

```
message = "Hello ${userService.getLoggedInUser()?.firstName ?: 'Anonymous'}!"
```